# How can I write a custom renderer for SfListView to disable scrolling?

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I am using SfListView due to grouping and other features available.
However, I need to disable scrolling  the list view in Android and iOS.
How do I write a custom renderer for SfListView?
For the Xamarin forms ListView, I can just extend the ListViewRenderer class  and override OnElementChanged method.

Also, how can I export the custom renderer?

For example, the below code would work for Xamarin forms ListView (with respective modifications ):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SfListViewWithNoScroll), typeof(SfListViewWithNoScrollRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Mobile.Droid.CustomRenderers
    {
    public class SfListViewWithNoScrollRenderer : //which class do I need to inherit?
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SfListView> e)
        {

            //base.OnElementChanged(e);
            //if (Control != null)
            //{
            //    Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            //}
            //what do I write here?
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this would affect the scrolling of the ListView but interaction like selection would still work out. You can't view the items below the viewport area.

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SfListView), typeof(CustomSfListViewRenderer))]
    namespace XamarinSfListViewDemo.Droid
    {
        public class CustomSfListViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<SfListView,Android.Views.View>
        {
            private Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView scroller;

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SfListView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                var element = e.NewElement;
                scroller = (Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView)typeof(SfListView).GetField("scrollView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(element);
                scroller.InputTransparent = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't tried this code in iOS but 90% it should work. Give it a try and let me know whether it helps!

Comment: Gives a 'null reference exception' in line  `scroller = (Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView)typeof(SfListView).GetField("scrollView", BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    .GetValue(element);`.   Even after changing this line to the one mentioned here : https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/129969/how-can-i-write-a-custom-renderer-for-sflistview , I get the same error

Comment: scroller = (Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView)typeof(SfListView).GetField("scrol‌​lView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ) .GetValue(element);

Comment: can you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679889/multiple-behaviors-in-entrybindable-property-change-is-not-reflected

Answer (score 0):

In SfListView, we have property “**IsScrollBarVisible**” for your requirement “Enable/disable the ScrollBar visibility in ListView”. No need to create renderer for this. By default, the IsScrollBarVisible property value is true. You can enable/disable the scrollbar visibility for specific platforms as like below code example.

```
<sync:SfListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding BookInfo}"> 
  <sync:SfListView.IsScrollBarVisible> 
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean"> 
      <OnPlatform.Android> 
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" Phone="false" Tablet="false"/> 
      </OnPlatform.Android> 
      <OnPlatform.iOS> 
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" Phone="false" Tablet="false"/> 
      </OnPlatform.iOS> 
      <OnPlatform.WinPhone> 
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" Phone="true" Tablet="true"/> 
      </OnPlatform.WinPhone> 
    </OnPlatform> 
  </sync:SfListView.IsScrollBarVisible> 
</sync:SfListView>
```

But it has got some limitations. Due to some restrictions in native ScrollView renderer in Xamarin Forms, you cannot change the IsScrollBarVisible property at runtime. It can be defined only while initializing the SfListView.